# Wordpress PHP Warning: Illegal offset type in unset

Tags: php, offset, unset

I'm using the following code for pagination, it is working properly but throwing a PHP Warning: Illegal offset type in unset in `(unset($allcategories[$parentc]);)`

Don't have a lot of experience in PHP, but can you guys guide me where my issue is? Thanks in advance.

```
<nav class="navigation post-navigation" role="navigation">
<h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'ci' ); ?></h1>

<?php 
$allcategories = get_terms(
  array( 'category' ), // Taxonomies
  array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) // Fields

);

$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );

foreach ($post_categories as $pc) {
if(($key = array_search($pc,$allcategories)) !== false) {
    unset($allcategories[$key]);
}
$this_category = get_category($pc);
if ($this_category->category_parent != '') {
    $parentc = get_category($this_category->category_parent);
    unset($allcategories[$parentc]);
}

}

?>
<div class="nav-links">
    <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link('%link', '%title', FALSE, $allcategories ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title', FALSE, $allcategories ); ?></div>

</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: check what are you getting in `$parentc`?

Comment: WP_Term Object
(
[term_id] => 4
[name] => DFW Metro
[slug] => dallas-fort-worth
[term_group] => 0
[term_taxonomy_id] => 4
[taxonomy] => category
[description] =>
[parent] => 0
[count] => 4883
[filter] => raw
[term_icon] =>
[cat_ID] => 4
[category_count] => 4883
[category_description] =>
[cat_name] => DFW Metro
[category_nicename] => dallas-fort-worth
[category_parent] => 0
)

Comment: That's only one object record

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
$parentc = get_category($this_category->category_parent);
```

The `get_category()` function is returning an object. Objects are not allowed as keys for an array. You are probably looking to do...

```
unset($allcategories[$parentc->term_id]);
```

Comment: i also recommend to debug like `print_r($parentc);`